# How to integrate iframe with 100% height and with page scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to insert a iframe in to a webpage with following requirements:

1. iframe height must be 100% - it should stretch the height with its content.
2. iframe scrollbars should not be visible, but the page scrollbars should be there with relevant to the height of the iframe contents.
3. iframe source is from a different domain.

Once the iframe is integrated, the web page should be as a single normal web page. I have styled the page and the iframe source page to match each other.

I tried different solutions by searching, but so far no luck.

Please give me a help

Thank You

Comment: Just a warning... In my experience, using 100% height can be shaky at best for browser compatibility - especially with legacy browsers.

Comment: can you add the image file here?

Comment: Do you have anything you've tried before?

Comment: Thank you all for your supports.
But  I figured out one thing, if Change the iframe height to match the iframe source file height everything is fine(eg: at one instance source height is 1346px, and changed the iframe height to 1346px and worked as I want). So how to get the iframe sourch file height and set it to the iframe height? Please note that the iframe content height is dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use css as

```
iframe{
height: 250px; // whatever you want
}
```

[Link DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r9yQm/)

Comment: You may need to apply the same style to some parent elements (body, form, etc.).

Comment: height cannot be hard coded, iframe source file height is dynamic(its contents are dynamic). So according to that iframe height should be adjusted.

Comment: this website may be helpful to you. http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/iframe-height-scrollbar-example/

Answer (score 1):

try this code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>iframed site</title>
<style>
.restricted{
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 

    overflow-x: hidden;

    -ms-overflow-x: hidden; 


}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="http://www.mukhesh-blog.blogspot.com" class="restricted"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

or this....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>iframe example</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   html, body, div, iframe { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
   iframe { display:block; width:100%; border:none; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <iframe src="http://example.org/">
    <p><a href="http://example.org/">example.org</a></p>
   </iframe>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```